Having a trouble with gulp-imagemin
I'm having a trouble with gulp-imagemin. When I test the minify-image task, it can't run. I tried a lot of ways to fix it but every time it had a problem. Can someone help me to fix this? I need this very much.
how I import gulp & gulp-imagemin:
const gulp = require('gulp');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');

how I write the task:
// gulp.task('minifyimage', () =>
//     gulp.src('src/assets/img/*')
//         .pipe(imagemin())
//         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img/'))
// );

gulp.task('minifyimage', async function () {
    return gulp
        .src('src/assets/img/*')
        .pipe(imagemin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img/'));
});

// export default () => (
//     gulp.src('src/images/*')
//         .pipe(imagemin())
//         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'))
// );

// function imgSquash() {
//     return gulp
//         .src('src/assets/img/*')
//         .pipe(imagemin())
//         .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/img/'));
// }

fix this problem. just fix this problem.
here is the problem:

PS C:\Users\Matin\Downloads\gulpApp> gulp optimize-images
[03:48:08] Loaded external module: C:\Users\Matin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\interpret\cjs-stub
(node:23416) ExperimentalWarning: CommonJS module C:\Users\Matin\Downloads\gulpApp\gulpfile.cjs is loading ES Module C:\Users\Matin\Downloads\gulpApp\node_modules\gulp-imagemin\index.js using require().
Support for loading ES Module in require() is an experimental feature and might change at any time
(Use node --trace-warnings ... to show where the warning was created)
Error: require() cannot be used on an ESM graph with top-level await. Use import() instead. To see where the top-level await comes from, use --experimental-print-required-tla.
